# aframe is not showing in webview android

Tags: android, android-webview, aframe

I am trying to load *https://aframe.io/aframe/examples/boilerplate/panorama/* inside webview but its not showing up. If i load the same url in mobile browser its loading correctly. I tested with pixel 2 virtual device with android version 24 and redmi k20 pro physical device. In both the cases its not loading.

my code looks like this,

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
myWebView.loadUrl("https://aframe.io/aframe/examples/boilerplate/panorama/");
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks that WebGL is not available on WebViews for your combination of device and Android version. You can check other WebGL websites to confirm. e.g: https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_colors

Related: [Android WebView and WebGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35746920/android-webview-and-webgl)

Comment: thanks for the reply but I configured webview as shown in this thread *https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/3243* and its working now in the physical device.